# Only one timer working at the time (html+js)

Tags: javascript, html

I have one timer and i want it in two different places in my website. But only one is working at the time.

Here is Script + first timer below it.

```
 <script>
    var interval;
    var minutes = 8;
    var seconds = 41;
    window.onload = function() {
        countdown('countdown');
        myFunction();
        myFunctiontoo();

    }

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById("timerx");
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    el.innerHTML = "Free trial bonus has expired!";                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + '';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>

    <div class="countdown"><span style="color:#EA0423;">Free Trial bonus ends in </span><span id="timerx" style="font-weight:bold;">8 minutes and 42 seconds</span>.
  </div>
```

A bit lower in my HTML code i have another timer.

```
<span style="color:#FFF1D6;">Free Trial bonus ends in </span><span id="timerx" style="font-weight:bold;">8 minutes and 42 seconds</span>.
```

The second timer unfortunately is not working.

Comment: You cannot define an ID more then once on a page. It has to be unique. Use a class instead and look for that.

Comment: change ID to class... if you have more than 1 element with same ID then jQuery will consider only 1st ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method getElementById other than getElementsByClassName return only one DOM element.

Method getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements so you can get them using an index

Here is working example: [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/jwO3mxyR89MrUvHKWzRY?p=preview;)

You can us getElementsByClassName and your code would look like this:

```
    function countdown(element) {
    var start_value = "Free trial bonus has expired!"
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName("timerx")[0];
        var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName("timerx")[1];
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                el1.innerHTML = start_value;                    
                el2.innerHTML = start_value;                    
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el1.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + '';
        el2.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + '';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Forgot that i was using id instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the timer twice in the same page you need to have  two IDs. The id="timerx"

```
<span id="timerx_"<?php echo 'DYNAMIC VARIBALE'; ?>>timer</span>
```

And use this new ID